# How to solve MySQL jdbc socket closed SocketException?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sockets, jdbc

There is on error that appears in my log file every time:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Socket closed
STACKTRACE:
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1994)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2916)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3179)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1207)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyStatement.java:35)
```

It happens always in the same point of the code, when the application does a specific query in the MySQL database.

The query is LIKE THIS:

```
SELECT M.*, O.id 
FROM order_message M 
INNER JOIN orders O ON M.order_id = O.id 
WHERE O.seller_id = 14224 AND M.sender_user_id <> 14224 
ORDER BY M.creation_date DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

I noticed (by EXPLAINING this query) that it always use temporary/filesort to execute. All indexes are properly created and I think these is no way to improve this, but I suspect the query performance or resource utilization is causing the exception error.

I am using amazon RDS

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce this with c3p0 out of the picture?

Comment: Please show the Java code which calls this query, as well as all other pertinent code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my connection pool was configured in a way that any database connection that took longer than 10 seconds would be dropped by the connection pool (c3p0). I was using the unreturnedConnectionTimeout parameter.

The c3p0 documentation page discourage to use this parameter. Ideally, all connections should be properly closed (and thus returned to the pool)

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout

I have increased the parameter to 60 seconds and the problem get solved.